# Connect to SQL Server on a productive Client

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have looked for multiple Solutions for my Problem.

I have a program, that needs to insert/update/select data from a Database nearly all the time. And the program itself works, but the problem is, it should also work in a production system with our staff and this needs to be secure.

One of the main thing is: 
How do I manage, that the program can connect to the DataBase from our Staff PC's, without mentioning in the Connection String the Username and Password.
Some People said, I should use Windows Authentication.

But where do I mention the user/password that will be used to connect to the database? I need it to work in a way, people cant see the Login-Data to manipulate the DB-Server, but the programm itself should still be able to connect to it.

How can I do it?

Here are 2 connection strings my Visual Studio generated for me:

```
"Data Source=domain,Port;Initial Catalog=Zeiterfassung;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=PW"

"Data Source=domain;Initial Catalog=Zeiterfassung;Integrated Security=True"
```

First one works fine, but the password is visible there. That shouldn't be. Even if I store it somewhere in the program, a decompiler will still make it visible.

Will the second string really work on ANY PC out there, that has internet connection and the program? So no one can see the Information need to Manipulate the program outside of the program or the Admin itself? Right now I can test on authorized PC's, that have a user which is manually added as authorized on the DB-Server, but what is with other users? The should only be able to connect to the DB with the Program, not manually with their Windows Account in MSSMS. Last thing should really be forbidden.

A Simple Code Snippet to clarify how the Connection looks for Example:

```
class Utility {

    private static SqlConnection con;
    static Utility() {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.DBPath1;
    }

    public static DataTableReader getSelectDataTableReader(string selectCommand, SqlParameter[] parameter) {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, con);
        if (parameter.Length > 0) {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameter);
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try {
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            writeToLog(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return ds.Tables["Table"].CreateDataReader();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about a TrustedConnection.  Suggest you look that up on your favorite search engine.  You will have to create a SQL Login for each authorized user.

Comment: `Integrated Security` will use the user-account permissions in order to run. If the user-account has the permissions to run, then it will run just fine. The issue with this is running it on multiple other computers where each user-account may have different permissions.

Comment: Thats the Problem. I cant add every User to the DB, cause 1. all ppl can manipulate the DB without the Programm and 2. its even planned to sell it in the future. There has to be a way, the Programm can do things with the DB, without adding 12345678 Users to the DB and without showing the login data

Comment: Set database to use Windows Credentials and setup a group account in Windows for the credentials.  The connection string should have Integrated Security = True which indicates to use Windows Credentials.  Then add all users to the windows group account.

Comment: This is extremely broad question. There are few different connections going on - connection to DB and connection to Application. Connection to APP can be via windows auth, but connection to DB via win auth is bad idea. Applications usually connect with same user to DB, connection string is encrypted and stored on server. The DB connection is configured to a specific role that gives specific privileges. Otherwise some user must have DB privileges? this is BAD

Comment: Does the second one give you any problem? Also consider the answer given below.